# Best way to get a label to change text/ redirect page after delay

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to implement in asp.net (c#) the following flow:

1. User clicks on a button
2. A text label presented
3. Waiting for 3 seconds
4. Reloading the page

I have been trying a few things in c# but i'm starting to think it's easier implement this in javascript

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you try my answer

Answer (score 0):

try like this

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript"> function callthis() {
> setTimeout('window.location = "home.aspx"', 3000); }
> </script>
> ```

call this from server side on button click

If you Used Update Panels Then You can Use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "callthis();", true);
```

Other Wise You can Use

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
        (GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "callthis();",true);
```

Comment: Hi sorry have been away for a while so didn't have time to test. It works to redirect the page to 'home.aspx' but refreshed continuously every 3 seconds not just the once. That is 1 problem the next is the address I need to navigate to as it contains a querystring which will be different each time so cannot be hard coded.

Comment: Try "window.location = window.location"